# Circle position of slides in upper navigation bar of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, spacing, circles, navigation

can anybody help me?
I would like the circles in my upper navigation bar of beamer slides to be centered.

The code I have now is the following:

```
\documentclass[8pt,hideothersubsections]{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm} 
\graphicspath{{./immagini/}}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eurosym}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\thmhead}[3]{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{es}{Esercizio}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definizione}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ese}{Esempio}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{conge}{Congettura}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usecolortheme[named=red]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,25}]{structure} 
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\definecolor{darkcyan}{rgb}{0.0, 0.55, 0.55}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usecolortheme[named=darkcyan]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{logonuovo}{logo_Unibg}

\titlegraphic{\pgfuseimage{logonuovo}}
\title{Persistent and Temporary Efficiency in Airport Cost Function}
\author[Gianmaria Martini]{Gianmaria Martini$^\S$, Davide Scotti$^\S$, Domenico Viola$^*$ \& Giorgio Vittadini$^{\dag}$}

%{{\textbf{Gianmaria Martini}$^\S$}, {\textbf{Davide Scotti}$^\S$}, {\textbf{Domenico Viola}$^*$} \& {\textbf{Giorgio Vittadini}$^{\dag}$}
%    \\
%   \textbf{Presentation by Gianmaria Martini}\\
%   \textbf{2017 ATRS World Conference--Antwerp} \\
\institute[Universit\`a degli Studi di Bergamo]
{
\small{$^\S$Universit\`a degli Studi di Bergamo} \\
\small{$^*$Universit\`a degli Studi di Bari} \\
\small{$^{\dag}$Universit\`a degli Studi di Milano--Bicocca} \\
}


\date{July 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Outline}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline of presentation}   % Insert frame title between curly braces
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Motivation}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Motivation \#1}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Motivation \#2}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Motivation \#3}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}

\section{Data}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Data \#1}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Data \#2}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Data \#3}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}


\section{Literature}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Literature \#1}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Literature \#2}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Literature \#3}   % Insert frame title 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Do you mean centered under the name of the section they belong to?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the option `compress` to the theme `Berlin` like this

```
\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}
```

This will put the circles (or mini frames, as they are called in `beamer`) right below the section titles.

Without `compress`:

[image: without compress]

With `compress`:

[image: with compress]